# Could not initialize class com.ibm.nosql.json.resources.Messages when using db2 NoSQLClient?

Tags: jakarta-ee, db2, websphere-liberty

I'm getting the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.nosql.json.resources.Messages
```

I understand that **NoClassDefFoundError** means that during runtime, the class could not be found.

The reason I am perplexed is because I successfully included a different class that resides in the same JAR file that is definately being detected by virtue that I am not getting the following error that was appearing prior to when I included the jar file:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/nosql/json/api/NoSQLClient
```

As per [the documentations](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1307nosqlforjson3/), I added  `C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\json\lib` to the CLASSPATH, I added it to the Java build path, and I also have it defined in my server.xml file:

```
    <library id="NOSQLJSONLIB">
        <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\json\lib" includes="nosqljson.jar"/>
    </library>

    <webApplication id="WebApi" location="WebApi.war" name="WebApi" contextRoot="/">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="NOSQLJSONLIB" />
    </webApplication>
```

Inside eclipse, I SEE com.ibm.nosql.json.resources.Messages class.

Finally, here is the code that fails:

```
DB db = NoSQLClient.getDB(databaseUrl, user, password, ns);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest to move library files out of Program files folder. Create directory with path without space, and put jars there.

Comment: That solved the problem. Would you post an answer?

Comment: where can we download  nosqljson.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to move library files out of Program files folder. Create directory with path without space, and put jars there.